# Varnish - TTL and the current Date

Tags: varnish

I'd like to set the TTL based on the current date.

http://site.com/2011/03/ should have 5 days as TTL.
 
http://site.com/2011/04/ should have 1 day as TTL.
Current Date: 15 April 2011

How is this possible in varnish?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Varnish honors the cache-headers sent by the backend - so setting appropriate expires-timestamps on your backend would be the best way to solve it.

If that is not an option, you would need to either develop a vmod, or implement this in in-line C within the VCL.

Developing a VMod, or writing in-line C in VCL is probably outside the scope of Serverfault, and should be brought up at Stack Overflow.